# SQL Server 2008 Error 201 - Procedure Expects Parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written the following USP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_M_InsertRegistration]
    @Reg_ID varchar(max),
    @Reg_UserID varchar(max),
    @Reg_Password varchar(max) ,
    @Reg_UserName varchar(max) ,
    @Reg_ContactNo varchar(max),
    @Reg_EmailId varchar(max) ,
    @City_ID varchar(max) ,
    @City_StateID varchar(max) ,
    @City_CountryID varchar(max) ,
    @Reg_SecurityQuestion varchar(max),
    @Reg_Answer varchar(max) ,
    @Reg_IsActive varchar(max) ,
    @Reg_Remark varchar(max) ,
    @Reg_CVPath varchar(max) ,
    @CreatedBy varchar(max) ,
    @CreatedDate varchar(max),
    @ModifiedBy varchar(max) ,
    @ModifiedDate varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OutMsg VARCHAR(Max)
    DECLARE @intErrorCode INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM M_Registration WHERE Reg_UserId = @Reg_UserID)--AND CreatedBy = @CreatedBy)
    BEGIN
            SET @OutMsg = 'false'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO M_Registration(
            Reg_UserID,
            Reg_Password,
            Reg_UserName,
            Reg_ContactNo,
            Reg_EmailId,
            City_ID,
            City_StateID,
            City_CountryID,
            Reg_SecurityQuestion,
            Reg_Answer,
            Reg_IsActive,
            Reg_Remark,
            Reg_CVPath,
            CreatedBy,
            CreatedDate)
        VALUES(
            @Reg_UserID,
            @Reg_Password,
            @Reg_UserName,
            @Reg_ContactNo,
            @Reg_EmailId,
            @City_ID,
            @City_StateID,
            @City_CountryID,
            @Reg_SecurityQuestion,
            @Reg_Answer,
            @Reg_IsActive,
            @Reg_Remark,
            @Reg_CVPath,
            @CreatedBy,
            GETDATE())
        SET @Reg_ID = @@IDENTITY
        END
END
GO
```

When trying to execute the stored procedure through SQL Server to test, it displays the error:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure usp_M_InsertRegistration, Line 0
>   Procedure or function 'usp_M_InsertRegistration' expects parameter
>   '@Reg_ID', which was not supplied.

I am unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: how are you trying to execute your sp?, are you passing all the parameters needed?

Comment: 1) Provide @Reg_ID to `EXEC [dbo].[usp_M_InsertRegistration] @Reg_ID = ` Or set default in  code `@reg_Id NVARCHAR(MAX) = <value>`

Comment: `SET @Reg_ID = @@IDENTITY` what is for at the end of stored procedure?

Comment: Well, **show us HOW** you execute this stored procedure!

Comment: See [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) - don't just use `varchar(max)` everywhere out of lazyness ...... - ***definitely NOT*** a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong with this procedure.

1. Variable `@Reg_ID` is of type `varchar(max)` where its purpose is to return the newly inserted identity value which is most probably Integer. So the datatype for this variable should be `INT`
2. The `@Reg_ID` is mentioned as input type parameter, since you are assigning it a value inside the procedure and most definitely want to know what it has been assigned to after procedure execution completes, you need to make it an `OUTPUT` parameter by mentioning the keyword `OUTPUT` next to it in procedure definition.

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_M_InsertRegistration]
         @Reg_ID INT OUTPUT,
          ........
   ```
3. You are using `@@IDENTITY` system function to capture the value of newly inserted identity value,  `@@IDENTITY` will return the newly inserted identity value across any session any table. You need to use `SCOPE_IDENTIT()` function which will only return the newly inserted identity value in your session/scope.